# Lambda function as class member

Tags: python

I am truing to write an idiomatic python here.

What is the best to write Lambda function as class member. and How can we comment it.

```
class foo:
    def run(self,x):
       """ I don't know what I am doing
       """
        return x*3


class foo:
    run= lambda x: x*3
```

Is there anyone to clarify this, from the lens of idiomatic python.

Comment: why would you use a lambda like that? It is certainly not idiomatic python

Comment: I am confused, cause I read that one-line functions should be written as lambda functions.

Comment: @user3378649 Lambdas are used mostly for callbacks and stuff. Functions like these are better written with `def`. That enables you to have them have a docstring and a proper name.

Comment: You should just use a normal method like your first example.

Comment: @user3378649 - lots of tutorials have examples like `fred = lambda x: x + 1`, but that is an abuse of lambdas. They should be used when you need to pass a short expression to a callable object but don't want to bother with writing a `def xxx():` for it.

Comment: lambdas can only be expressions, not statements, and cannot be commented. Two reasons why `fred = lambda x: x + 1` is lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments it is in general not suported (in addition to being a poor use of a `lambda`)... however by convention you would comment them the same as any other class member

```
 #: returns the square
 fred = lambda x:x*x
```

or

```
 fred = lambda x:x*x   #: returns the square
```

or even(although less aesthetically pleasing)

```
 fred = lambda x:x*x
 ''' returns the square '''
```

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html#variable-docstrings

this method of documentation is pretty readable and is also supported by most auto-documentation tools

Answer (score 4):

It's not illegal to use a `lambda` like that, but it's silly.

The point of `lambda` is to conveniently make a very lightweight function object, one whose use is so ephemeral that it's not even worth the bother of giving it a name.  A classic example is simple callback functions for a GUI Framework:

```
shutdown_button_callbacks = {
    "on_mouse_click" : lambda: gui_shutdown("now"),
    "on_mouse_right_click": lambda: show_context_menu("shutdown_menu")
}
```

Since the callbacks here are really trivial, and they are just being poked into a `dict` for use by a GUI framework, it's convenient to just put them right there in the `dict` declaration.

If as you need to bind the function object to a name, you should just use a normal `def` statement.  This not only binds the name, but also sets the `.__name__` attribute on the function object, and it's the idiomatic way to do it in Python.

Python has a very limited `lambda` and the word from Guido van Rossum is that this will never change.  So as soon as you need anything other than a single expression, you can't use a `lambda` anyway.

Both the `def` statement and `lambda` make function objects; the only difference is that `def` binds a name.  You can still get a reference to the function object and store it, pass it around, etc.  There is nothing "better" or special about a `lambda` function object.

P.S. Another classic use of `lambda` would be for a simple code snippet for a `map()` call:

```
map(lambda x: x**2, range(9))  # returns squares of numbers 0 through 8 inclusive
```

But common practice in Python would be to use a list comprehension, and you can just put in the code snippet without making a function out of it:

```
[x**2 for x in range(9)]
```